# How to convert a SIM-card contact to be Google/device account instead?

Tags: android, android-contacts, sim-card

### Background

I'm trying to provide an easy way to convert a SIM card contact, to be a device or Google account contact.

### The problem

I tried to update its account directly, and I also tried to perform a transaction of delete&add.

Both ways didn't work.

I wish to do it atomically, so that if it fails, it won't let the address book have duplicates because of this, or even worse, not have the contact at all.

### What I've tried

As I wrote, both ways didn't work:

1.Code for trying to update directly (doesn't do anything):

```
public static Uri convertSimCardContactToNormalOne(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final String contactKey, @Nullable Account account) {
    final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
    final Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, contactKey);
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(contactUri).withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account == null ? null : account.type)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account == null ? null : account.name).build());
    final ContentProviderResult[] contentProviderResults;
    try {
        contentProviderResults = context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        Uri uri = contentProviderResults[contentProviderResults.length - 1].uri;
        return uri ;
    } catch (RemoteException | OperationApplicationException ignored) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

2.Code for trying to delete&add contact (seems to delete contact, but create an empty one instead) :

```
@RequiresPermission(permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
public static Uri convertSimCardContactToNormalOne(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final String contactKey, @Nullable Account account, @Nullable final String phoneNumber, @Nullable final String contactName, @Nullable final String emailAddress, @Nullable final Bitmap bitmap) {
    final Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, contactKey);
    final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(contactUri).build());
    int rawContactID = 0;
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account == null ? null : account.type)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account == null ? null : account.name)
            .build());
    if (contactName != null)
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contactName)
                .build());
    if (phoneNumber != null)
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber)
                .withValue(Phone.TYPE, CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .build());
    if (emailAddress != null)
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailAddress)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME).build());

    if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, stream.toByteArray())
                .build());
        try {
            stream.flush();
        } catch (IOException ignored{
        }
    }
    final ContentProviderResult[] contentProviderResults;
    try {
        contentProviderResults = context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        Uri uri = contentProviderResults[contentProviderResults.length - 1].uri;
        return uri ;
    } catch (RemoteException | OperationApplicationException ignored) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

### The questions

1. What am I doing wrong here? I know that if it's not within a transaction, method 2 will work, but now it doesn't for some reason.
2. What is the best way to convert such a contact?
3. Is there a way to go over all fields available for a single contact, and put them into a new contact (the converted one)?
4. Is there maybe also an intent for requesting such a thing (I still need code, but this could be useful in case it fails for some reason) ?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt method one could work, it may cause the SyncProviders of both the original account and the destination account confused to say the least, and might be considered a corruption of the DB to them.
SyncAdapter rely on internal SYNC1..SYNC4 fields, which us mortals don't understand, and you can't rely on the same `RawContact` to work as is on a different account.

Regarding method 2, I would try changing a number of things there:

1. Use `contactUri` as `Contacts.CONTENT_URI/contactId` and not `Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI/contactKey`, Lookup uris are used for finding a contact by searching it on the DB, not for modification purposes.
2. Move the delete op to the end.
3. Except for the `newInsert` first op, all other ops should copy **all the Data fields**, not just selected ones, all mimetypes store all values in DATA1..DATA15 possible fields, the specific names (e.g. `CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE`) are just suger-syntax to some DATA field, so I would do `.withValue(Data.DATA1, existingData1)` lines 15 times per `Data` entry you find.
4. You might find it useful to create a helper method that will return a new operation with all 15 values copied, and call it in a loop, adding the return values to the `ops` `ArrayList`.

Comment: 1. Isn't it what I already use? Please explain how. 2. But the transaction mean that first I don't want to have traces of the Sim-card-contact, and then create a new one, no? 3. Can you please show how? Also, aren't Sim-card-contacts only have name,email and phone ? 4. Makes sense, but won't it be even longer than what I did?

Comment: (1) you're using `CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI` in combination with `contactKey`, I would change that to `CONTENT_URI` w/ contactId. (2) it sounds safer to me to first add new data, then delete stale data, instead of the other way around (3) i'll try write some code when i have time. yes, but there are other fields on that data you're not taking into account in your copy

Comment: 1. I thought that lookup-key is best defined this way, that it doesn't change as much as contact id. 2. Since it's a transaction, it should be safe (atomic operation - all success or all fails). 3. Thank you. What other fields are there in Sim card contacts? Those are the only ones users can set, no?